# Can I make mesh curvy?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have this basic circle extruded and I want to know if, with the selected mesh, is there a way to make this mesh a smooth continuous curve, Not this jagged angle?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how I ended up doing it was, I extruded the circle straight out and then added a whole bunch of loop cuts to the ectruded circle. I then selected the desired circle of vertices and then moved the circle up using proportional editing. It worked beautifully!!